# Head on character reference photo is slightly turned, how can I straighten it?

Tags: photoshop, 3d, models

I'm using images from 3d.sk for character modeling and the one I'm using has his head turned slightly to the side. I tried lens correction but didn't really know what I was doing. Is there a way I can make it appear he's looking straight forward?

Comment: If available, a link to the photo would be a minimum requirement to answer that well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it an actual 3D model or a screenshot from a 3D model?

If it's the former then you can rotate either the model or orbit the camera to straighten the image.

If it's the latter then there's nothing straightforward you can do as the information you need isn't there. You *might* be able to get an artist to redraw the face as though it were full face.

From my brief perusal of the site it looks like all they offer is 2D images rather than the reference models (which makes sense from a business perspective).

Comment: Ya sorry it's a 2d image. What I decided to do was copy half the figure in Photoshop, and mirror it to the other so it looks symetrical.